# How to work with SVN version control in Lyx?

Tags: lyx, revision-control

In Lyx versions 1.6.8 and higher there is a version control toolbar.

I successfully got RCS working but I cannot find any information on how to use SVN.

However, there always is an "use SVN" button which is greyed out.

I added the bin directory of a slicksvn installation to the PathPrefix in the Lyx options as well as to the Path environment variable of WinXP, which is my operating system.

I saved preferences, reconfigured and restarted Lyx but SVN won't work.

How to get SVN up and running with Lyx?

Comment: This isn't a LaTeX problem.

Comment: If this is a question about LyX, then it is on-topic. However I couldn't find any use SVN button in LyX, grayed out or not. Nor did google tell me anything useful about that topic. Could you please add more details.

Answer (score 4):

I can't find a “Use SVN” button (in LyX 2.0.0 under Linux), but there is File > Version Control > Register.

According to the LyX manual, to use this you first have to put the directory with the LyX file under version control directly with the Subversion tools (using whatever slicksvn provides). Then you can tell LyX about it with File > Version Control > Register.

As I didn't want to set up an SVN server I couldn't try this, but this is how it ought to work according to the “Additional LyX Features” manual.